# Need to add border-radius to the border of an element

Tags: css

[image: Image to explain the issue]

I am adding a left border to the list-item element. width of border is 4px. Also, it needs to have rounded corners (border-radius of 4px).

Is this possible through CSS? I had gone through some tutorials and not able to fix this via CSS.

Comment: What have you tried and what problems are you having? Include your markup and styling in your question. I simply added `border-radius: 4px;` to a 4px left border and the left side of that border became curved.

Comment: @Riten were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want the bar at the left side (border) to have rounded top and bottom; if you are using a border, you can't exactly make it curve as I think you intend, you would need to create this bar separately to make it look with curved corners.

Now you can build this bar with a `div`, a `span` or even pseudo-elements like `:before`, that's up to you; but I just want to show you the logic behind what I mean withe the example below

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

.item {
  border-left: 4px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* Or
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  */
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.item2 {
  display: flex;
}

.item2 .bar {
  width: 4px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box item">
  <span>Your Text</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="box item2">
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
  <span>Your Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I like to use CSS :before and :after then you can write even less markup!

Comment: Definitely agree, just went for the more visually straightforward solution lol

Comment: You can use border-radius: 4px 4px; instead of {border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;}

Comment: @AntonioEsposito also true :) just wanted to avoid confusion; edited to reflect your point

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by pseudoclass `:before`

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
h1:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 4px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Element Text</h1>
```